# Does a micro-USB Bluetooth v4 dongle exist?

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I'm looking for a micro-USB Bluetooth dongle for my tablet. Do they exist?

For clarification, since my search terms keep just turning up the first image, I want one of these:

[image]

But instead with a plugin like this:

[image]

I know you can get cables to convert, but I'm hoping to be able to leave it plugged in, which would not be conducive with a cable hanging off.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have a full size SD card port by any chance? If so, you might be able to use an SDIO Bluetooth card: http://amzn.com/B00006347Q. Even with the right adapter, I don't think the USB Bluetooth adapter will be supported.

Comment: Currently they don't exist (AFAIK). I think you're stuck using a [USB->Micro-USB adapter](http://www.amazon.com/eForCity-Micro-Female-Male-Adaptor/dp/B0023FTRUO).  Having said that, this falls under the shopping request category (IMO anyway), which are off-topic for SU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would still stick out some, what about something like this?  It would be rigid and looks somewhat compact.  For $6.00 (before possible shipping), it may be worth a shot.

[Right Angle 90 Degree 5Pin Micro B Male to A Female + Micro USB Female Power Supply Plug Data OTG Host Converter Adapter Android](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Right-Angle-90-Degree-5Pin-Micro-B-Male-to-A-Female-Micro-USB-Female-Power-Charge/2036858428.html?plac&gclid=Cj0KEQiA592lBRCXy8yl4bjK17wBEiQAg1Az_dZGJzydNsr2wsDeg02hcfQ7D3AfO6UjzcYS4aG6lWwaAmgv8P8HAQ&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&albch=Google&netw=g&device=c&src=Google&cv=1020800000009057&isdl=y&ptsid=1020000000013095&af=ppc&crea=51413593585)

Comment: Good call. Assuming it's an Android tablet we're talking about here, do you know of it will recognize the Bluetooth adapter?

Comment: If this does work, keep in mind that it won't have the same functionality as integrated Bluetooth because the tablet will only be able to act as the slave device. If you're looking for Bluetooth audio only, a 3.5 mm Bluetooth audio adapter is a sure bet: http://www.amazon.com/Bluetooth-Receiver-Doosl-20-Hours-Streaming/dp/B00RCAXJ40/ref=cm_sw_em_r_awdtod_H3.Tub1ACNCFK_tt

Answer (score 0):

This item will convert your USB dongle with only 1/4?inch extension. Not perfect, but as good as you can get.
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/GS-2pcs-Micro-USB-Male-to-USB-Female-OTG-Adapter-Converter-For-Android-Tablet-Phone-Jun/32685227549.html?

Comment: We don't provide shopping recommendations here on SuperUser. There are several reasons, but the most important is that hardware changes quickly, and what is available or acceptable at one point will change or be no longer available shortly thereafter.